# Seemingly complex logic/set-theoretic puzzle

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

I got this puzzle some time ago and it has been bugging me since, I cant solve it - but it is supposedly solvable, I am interested in a solution or any tips on how to proceed.

In front of you is an entity named Adam. Adam is a 
solid block with a single speaker, through which 
he hears and communicates. For all propositions 
(statements that are either true or false) $p$, if 
$p$ is true and logically knowable to Adam, then 
Adam knows that $p$ is true. Adam is confined to his 
physical form, cannot move, and only has the sense 
of hearing. The only sounds Adam can make are to play 
one of two pre-recorded audio messages. One message 
consists of a very high note played for one second, 
and the other one a very low note played for one 
second.

Adam has mentally chosen a specific subset of the 
Universe of ordinary mathematics. The Universe 
of ordinary mathematics is defined as follows:

Let $S_0$ be the set of natural numbers:

$$S_0 = \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$$

$S_0$ has cardinality $\aleph_0$, the smallest and only 
countable infinity.

The power set of a set $X$, denoted $2^X$, is the set of all subsets 
of $X$. The power set of a set always has a cardinality 
larger than the set itself, $$|2^X| = 2^{|X|}$$

Let $S_1 = S_0 \cup 2^{S_0}$. $S_1$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0} = \beth_1$.

Let $S_2 = S_1 \cup 2^{S_1}$. $S_2$ has cardinality $2^{\beth_1} = \beth_2$.

In general, let $S_{n+1} = S_n \cup 2^{S_n}$. $S_{n+1}$ has cardinality $2^{\beth_n} = \beth_{n+1}$.

The Universe of ordinary mathematics is defined as $$\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty S_i$$

This Universe contains all sets of natural numbers, 
all sets of real numbers, all sets of complex numbers, 
all ordered $n$-tuples for all $n$, all functions, all 
relations, all Euclidean spaces, and virtually 
anything that arises in standard analysis.

The Universe of ordinary mathematics has cardinality 
$\beth_\omega$.

Your goal is to determine the subset Adam is thinking 
of, while Adam is trying to prevent you from doing so. 
You are only allowed to ask Adam yes/no questions in 
trying to accomplish your task. Adam must respond to 
each question, and does so by playing a single note. 
After Adam hears your question, he either chooses the 
low note to mean yes and the high note to mean no, or 
the high note to mean yes and the low note to mean no, 
for that question only. He also decides to either tell 
the truth or lie for each question after hearing it. 
If at any time you ask a question which cannot be 
answered by Adam without him contradicting himself, 
Adam will either play the low note or the high note, 
ignoring the question entirely.

Adam has given you an infinite amount of time to 
accomplish your task. More specifically, the set of 
both questions asked by you and notes played by Adam 
can be of any cardinality. If in your strategy this 
set is uncountably large, for any number of possibilities 
of Adam's chosen subset, you must describe the order that 
the elements of this set take place in as completely as 
possible.

During your questioning, you are keeping track of 
the following numbers:

$B_1 = $ The number of questions in which Adam had the option 
of truthfully responding in the affirmative. (This number 
and the following numbers can of course be cardinal numbers.)

$B_2 = $ The number of questions in which Adam had the option 
of truthfully responding in the negative.

$B_3 = $ The number of questions in which Adam had the option 
of falsely responding in the affirmative.

$B_4 = $ The number of questions in which Adam had the option 
of falsely responding in the negative.

$B_5 = $ The number of questions in which Adam responded 
with the high note.

$B_6 = $ The number of questions in which Adam responded 
with the low note.

$B_7 = $ The number of questions.

Let $C = B_1+B_2+B_3+B_4+B_5+B_6+B_7$

A strategy exists which will eventually allow you to 
determine Adam's chosen subset. Describe such a strategy 
in which $C$ is as small as possible, for all possibilities 
of Adam's chosen subset.

Comment: Sounds like a scene from Kubrick's *2001: A Space Odyssey*!

Comment: A small remark is that minimizing $C$ is equivalent to minimizing $B_1+\dots+B_7$, which is more palatable, so I would suggest to edit the question to redefine $C$ as this sum.  

Comment: @Andres Ok I hope you are right :)

Comment: It's fine that you post here as well, but at least acknowledge that you've posted it on MSE beforehand. http://math.stackexchange.com/q/17688/622

Comment: I don't get it.  It seems to me that the rules permit "Adam" to, for instance, play the high note in response to every question, no matter what subset he has chosen.  Did you mean to impose some consistency requirement on his answers?  (In particular, I'm not sure what is meant by "contradicting himself", since it seems he can answer each individual question however he wants.)  

Comment: I dont really have a definite answer to your question, but I have some ideas.

If you ask him "Is this statement false?" Then he can neither answer true/false as telling the truth nor lieng. So I guess there is some statements of this sort that one can use to extract some information of his set. 

Also, the statement "A strategy exists which will eventually allow you to determine Adam's chosen subset." could imply that if there is some sequence of high/low notes that makes it logically impossible to determine the set, then Adam can not play this sequence. 

Comment: @Pete I mean, we must assume the problem statement to be true to solve it, so there is the remote possibility that this imposes conditions on his high/low note sequence space.

Comment: Do you have the original source for this puzzle?

Comment: The problem is part of Unigeg World's Smartest Person Contest 2010, available at http://psiq.org/human_intelligence_test.pdf The instructions say, "discussing contents of test with others is prohibited...discussing answers with others is strictly prohibited...publishing test in full or part thereof is prohibited," but there's no indication of any prize on offer or any enforcement mechanism. 

Comment: @Peter: You can get around the lack of information about what the notes mean (at least for some interpretations of the question) using the trick described in the solution to the following puzzle:

http://web.jaguarpaw.co.uk/~tom/srcf/puzzles/evenharder.html

Comment: @Gerry So you/we just broke some law. 

Comment: In my opinion this is not a research-level math question, because (i) it has been taken from a list of puzzles almost verbatim (but without attribution), so (ii) it is not possible to get the OP to clarify the meaning of the question.  Having somewhat cryptic instructions may be okay for a puzzle, if you like that sort of thing.  It is not okay for a math question.

Comment: Pete, I'll take that as a motion to close, and will vote accordingly. 

Comment: By the way, how does Adam answer if you ask, "Have you stopped beating your wife?"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, observe that you can get around the difficulty that
you don't know if high means yes or low in the following
way. If you really want to ask the question $\varphi$, you
should instead ask the question *"high means yes for this round if and
only if $\varphi$"*. If high means yes, then this is the
same as asking $\varphi$. But if high means no, then it is like asking $\neg\varphi$, and so we may interpret a high anwer to this question as yes to $\varphi$.  This
transformation therefore ensures that we can in effect know
that high means yes. (I mentioned a similar trick in [this
MO
answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32269/guess-a-number-with-at-most-one-wrong-answer/32337#32337)
about guessing a number, when there can be wrong answers.)

For the lying issue, let me assume that by lying, you mean
that Adam first decides whether to lie or tell the truth,
and then calculates what a truthful answer would be, and
then when telling the truth plays the appropriate tone, but if lying
plays the opposite tone. With this interpretation, a
similar trick allows us to extract the desired information.
Namely, if you want to ask $\psi$, instead ask *"you have decided to be truthful for this question iff $\psi$"*. If Adam decides to
be truthful, then this question is answered the same as
$\psi$. If he decides to lie, then he calculates what a
truthful answer would be, given that he has already decided
to lie, which is the opposite of $\psi$, and so he says the
opposite of this. In this way, the double negation of the
transformation allows us to get the desired information.

Combining the two transformations allows us to get answers
to any desired question.

Now, we simply proceed as follows. Since it seems
permissible in the world of your question, let us enumerate
all the elements of what you call the universe of ordinary
mathematics, and ask of each such element whether it is in
Adam's set, using the transformations above. In this way,
we find out exactly the set of which he is thinking.

The end result is $\beth_\omega$ many questions. This is the optimal in the sense that any smaller bound on the number of questions would be less than $\beth_n$ for some $n$, with only $\beth_{n+1}$ many possible patterns of answers, but there are $\beth_{\omega+1}$ many sets that Adam might be considering.

Incidently, what you call the universe of ordinary mathematics
is closely related to what is known in set theory as
$V_{\omega+\omega}$, which is a model of the Zermelo axioms
of set theory, one of the first axiomatizations of set theory. The $V$ hierarchy begins with $V_0$ being
the empty set, and $V_{\alpha+1}=P(V_\alpha)$ and
$V_\lambda=\bigcup_{\alpha\lt\lambda} V_\alpha$ for limit
ordinals $\lambda$. Your universe is contained within
$V_{\omega+\omega}$, but is actually missing huge parts of
$V_{\omega+1}$, because you started only with the natural
numbers, rather than the hereditary finite sets. For
example, the set $\{\ a_k\mid k\in\mathbb{N}\ \}$, where
$a_k=\{\{\{\cdots\}\}\}$ has depth $k$, is missing
from your universe, but exists in $V_{\omega+1}$. It follows that your world of mathematics does not have the set HF consisting of all hereditary finite sets, or any similar set with unbounded finite depths. From this, it follows that your world does not satisfy some of the very elementary axioms of set theory, which would allow you to construct HF from the natural numbers. For example, the set mentioned above is the result of a very simple induction on finite-depth finte sets.

The fact that $V_{\omega+\omega}$ itself has no sets of size $\beth_\omega$ is precisely what led to the realization that the Zermelo axioms are too weak to prove even that $\beth_\omega$ exists. This realization led directly to the 
addition of the Replacement axiom to the axioms of set theory, resulting in the theory now known as ZFC.

Answer (score 4):

I wonder why Adam cannot reason as follows:

If the answer to the question is yes, then I will answer truthfully and use the high note to mean "yes".  Thus I will play the high note.

If the answer to the question is no, then I will answer truthfully and use the high note to mean "no".
Thus I will play the high note.

Suppose I get asked a question of the form "Does the high note mean 'yes' iff $\varphi$?"  Well, I don't know whether the high note means yes until I know what the answer to the question is.  But if $\varphi$ is true and I assume that the high note means 'yes', then the answer is 'yes', which I will signify by playing the high note.  So this is at least a consistent answer.  If $\varphi$ is true and I assume that the high note means "no", then the answer to the question is "no", which I will signify by playing the high note.  Thus, so long as $\varphi$ is true, it doesn't matter whether I think the high note means 'yes' or 'no', since both assumptions are consistent and lead to the same answer: play the high note.

Now suppose $\varphi$ is false.  Assume first that the high note means 'yes'.  Then the answer to the question is 'no', so since I will answer truthfully and play the high note, the answer is no.  That's a contradiction.  So now let me assume that the high note means 'no'.  Then the answer to the question is 'yes', so then the high note signifies 'yes', also a contradiction!  What do I do in this situation?  Ah, the rules say that if there is no way to answer without contradicting myself, then I can answer however I want.  I will play the high note, since I am after all supposed to be giving away as little information as possible and if I play the high note every time then I am obviously giving away no information whatsoever.

Comment: Pete, I assume your answer is a response to Joel's answer?  In his solution, you don't simply ask "Does high mean 'yes' iff $\varphi$?", you have to combine it with the strategy to deal with lying, so you'd ask: "Is it the case that this is a truth-telling round iff (this is a high-means-'yes' round iff $\varphi$)?"

Comment: Pete, my solution interprets the procedure as: first the question is asked, then Adam decides on meaning of high/low and whether to tell truth/lie, and then he answer accordingly. In particular, the truth conditions for the statement should be determined after the choices are made, and clearly my solution depends on this. If we allow Adam to determine the truth conditions before making the decisions, then I agree with you that we can learn nothing from him. In this case, the true nature of Adam would have to be clarified. A similar issue arises in the answer I linked to in my answer.  

Comment: @Amit: my response is motivated by Joel's answer.  I argue that there is an interpretation of the question under which Adam can play the high tone every time, which clearly gives away no information.  Because Joel gave a winning strategy under a different interpretation, I decided to clarify why in my interpretation the questions in Joel's strategy don't work.  To simplify things, I made Adam's strategy such that he always tells the truth, so questions which ask about truth do not need to be considered.

Comment: @Pete It appears that Joel's answer was not the authors intended answer. I have found a newer version of the puzzle which seems to disallow such questions. http://seti.weebly.com/uploads/1/8/2/4/1824936/profoundintelligencetest1.pdf

Comment: This seems to throw doubt on the credentials of those trying to evaluate the "World's Smartest Person"...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers proposed to this question, I think this problem is ill-defined. The set of possible questions and assignment of truth valuations is not well defined. A fair definition of a "question" would be to specify a sset $X \subseteq \beth_\omega$, where yes means that the chosen set is inside $X$ and no means it is not. In this case, Pete's answer obviously proves that Adam always has a winning strategy.